# Can't share PHP PDO project with ngrok : FATAL ERROR

Tags: php, pdo, localhost, ngrok

**FOUND SOLUTION :
I had to add the port and replace localhost by 127.0.0.1 in the DSN**

I have a problem with all my PHP websites connected with PDO when I try to share them with ngrok : I get a PDO exception but all works fine in local...

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such
>   file or directory in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cours/PHP/chatbox/Final/php/bdd.class.php:12
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cours/PHP/chatbox/Final/php/bdd.class.php(12):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'root', Array) #1
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cours/PHP/chatbox/Final/php/discussion.class.php(7):
>   BDD->__construct() #2
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cours/PHP/chatbox/Final/php/controller.php(31):
>   Discussion->__construct() #3 {main} thrown in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cours/PHP/chatbox/Final/php/bdd.class.php on
>   line 12

All my links are relative

Here a piece of code (very basic)

```
include "bdd.class.php";
include "discussion.class.php";
include "message.class.php";
```

And where the error is declared (in my bdd.class.php) :

```
$this->bdd = new PDO (
            'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=chatbox;charset=UTF8',
            'root',
            'root',
            [
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
            ]
            );
```

Do you have any idea of how to make it work when it is shared with ngrok ?

Best

Comment: Did you google for `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]`? If not, can you?

Comment: Indeed, if I replace localhost by 127.0.0.1 and add port to the DSN it works ! thanks